# SQl queries are throwing error maria Db Offset Problem laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Recently I have deleted my vendor folder and reinstalled. After that my all get queries are throwing error. Since I am new to php and laravel I have no clue what i am missing.

Thanks

/*Error*/

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 0' at line 1

My Code:

```
public function couponList(Request $request){
        $sort_by = $request->get('sort-by');
        $order_by = $request->get('order-by');
        $homeTitle = 'Coupons and List'; 
        $coupons = DB::table('sb_coupons AS CO')
        ->select('CO.*','CO.status as couponStatus','CO.created_at as couponOrderDate','UT.*',
        'UT.firstname as userName')
        ->leftJoin('sb_customer AS UT', 'UT.customer_id', '=', 'CO.user_id');
        if(!empty($request->s)){
            $coupons->Where('CO.coupon_code', 'like', '%' . $request->s . '%');
        }
        if ($request->has('status')) {
            $coupons->where('CO.status', $request->status);
        }
        $coupons = $coupons->paginate(env('RECORD_PER_PAGE'));              
        $coupons->appends($request->s); 

        return view('admin.coupons.coupon-list',array('homeTitle'=>$homeTitle,'coupons'=>$coupons,'params'=>$request, 'sort_by'=> $sort_by , 'order_by' => $order_by))
        ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * env('RECORD_PER_PAGE'));
    }
```

***.env *

```
APP_NAME=DeliverMyOrders
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:LiLofkwJXFVZd4ZeUvGz/UADUFOeqx+Yeqv7L1gBHvY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=delivermyorders
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
RECORD_PER_PAGE=10

FACEBOOK_ID=458516817946384
FACEBOOK_SECRET=9660233aee1cf8b443e4586ea864ea1a
FACEBOOK_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback/


GOOGLE_ID=1512483269952
GOOGLE_SECRET=AIzaSyB-AiSA4Kd-R36M6J7NSTXxAWbVs7z4C_s
GOOGLE_URL=http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback
```

Comment: How odd. Is there a part of the error that shows the full query? Or can you try `Log::info($coupons->toSql());` right before paginate to see what most of the query looks like? It will place a log file in `storage/logs` that would have the results.

Comment: Log is not implemeted in my project

Comment: You can use `dd` instead of `Log::info`, then, which will dump and die, or just `var_dump`

Comment: @aynber ---  "select `CO`.*, `CO`.`status` as `couponStatus`, `CO`.`created_at` as `couponOrderDate`, `UT`.*, `UT`.`firstname` as `userName` from `sb_coupons` as `CO` left join `sb_customer` as `UT` on `UT`.`customer_id` = `CO`.`user_id`"

Comment: 'select `CO`.*, `CO`.`status` as `couponStatus`, `CO`.`created_at` as `couponOrderDate`, `UT`.*, `UT`.`firstname` as `userName` from `sb_coupons` as `CO` left join `sb_customer` as `UT` on `UT`.`customer_id` = `CO`.`user_id`'

Comment: `$coupons->toSql()` won't help, because `offset` comes from `->paginate(...)`. But I wonder, why the exception message doesn't contain the full query.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel True, I was just curious if the issue came before then, and I'm not sure if you can use toSql after paginate. I was really hoping the full query was in the error message.

Comment: @aynber any suggestions for this error. I am still struggling

Comment: Is the error message showing the full query string?

Comment: No. I tried debugging. In vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
In this peice it breaks $results = $total ? $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->get($columns) : collect();

Comment: Is the error message happening on `paginate`, or `appends`?

Comment: protected function runSelect()
    {
        return $this->connection->select(
            $this->toSql(), $this->getBindings(), ! $this->useWritePdo
        );
    }

Error happens at this piece it tries ti run the qury

Comment: It happens in paginate

Comment: Try `dd($this->toSql());` right before that select inside of the function, see what it shows.

Comment: select * from `sb_admin` where `id` = ? limit 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207195/discussion-between-amit-and-aynber).

Comment: That must be a completely different query... it's probably dying on the first query instead of the one that's breaking. I'm surprised that `Log` isn't implemented, since it comes default with Laravel. It'd be easier to log every query instead of dying. Maybe use `var_dump` instead?

Comment: I am really not sure why this is happening this was running fine until I updated my vendor folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue finally by downgrading database version .

In composer.json in "require"

```
"illuminate/database": "4.1.10"
```